# Why I can't set breakpoint on linux kernel entry in QEMU?

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, gdb, qemu

Recently, I began to debug Linux kernel 5.18.10 with QEMU(qemu-system-x86_64) and gdb. I know that the BIOS of QEMU would load kernel code to 0x10000 when QEMU was startup, and the first instruction that QEMU would execute in Linux kernel is in 0x10200. So I set a breakpoint on 0x10200. While after a `continue` command was sent to gdb, it received the message of "Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap." and then EIP was set to 0x0. So I can't debug the Linux booting progress.

I want to ask if anyone can figure it out? Thanks a lot.

Words below are my actions and output in QEMU and gdb.

1. run QEMU:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel ./arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage \
                   -device virtio-serial \
                   -chardev pty,id=virtiocon0 -device virtconsole\
                   -drive file=core-image-minimal-qemux86.ext4,if=virtio,format=ra\
                   --append "root=/dev/vda loglevel=15 console=tt\
                   -nographic \
                   -m 256 -s -S
```

2. run gdb:

```bash
gdb /home/wt/gitrepo/linux/vmlinux
```

and my .gdbinit

```
add-auto-load-safe-path /home/wt/gitrepo/linux/scripts/gdb/vmlinux-gdb.py
dir /home/wt/gitrepo/linux
target remote :1234
```

3. set breakpoint on 0x10200:

```bash
// output of gdb
(gdb) b *0x10200
Breakpoint 1 at 0x10200
```

4. continue on gdb:

```
// output of QEMU
SeaBIOS (version 1.15.0-1)


iPXE (https://ipxe.org) 00:03.0 CA00 PCI2.10 PnP PMM+0FF8B2A0+0FECB2A0 CA00



Booting from ROM..
```

```bash
// output of gdb
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x0000000000000000 in fixed_percpu_data ()
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x0000000000000000 in fixed_percpu_data ()
```

Comment: And when run QEMU without '-s -S' options, I can enter Linux normally.

Comment: What happens when you set the breakpoint on a symbol, like `main` or `console_init`?

Comment: When I set the breakpoint at `console_init` and hit `continue` on gdb, the running stop at `console_init()` as below said:


(gdb) b console_init
Breakpoint 1 at 0xffffffff82fbb250: file kernel/printk/printk.c, line 3236.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, console_init () at kernel/printk/printk.c:3236
3236    {

Comment: I don't have an exact answer now. But I guess that the bootloader in QEMU would set IDTR to a bad value, resulting that gdb's breakpoint mechanism through INT3 cause a bad trap. Is it possible that this is the reason?

Comment: have you ever solved this problem? actually I encounter almost the same problem

Comment: Have you ever tried to disable the kaslr and set a breakpoint on the right start entry? [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397939/turning-off-kaslr-to-debug-linux-kernel-using-qemu-and-gdb) is how to disable the kaslr when run qemu.